# Precautions when developing ASP.NET application on x86 computers but target computer is 64 bit (Windows Server 2008)

Tags: .net, asp.net, windows-server-2008, x86-64

We have to deploy our application on a Windows 2008 64 bit server. As the application is already running for over one year on a Windows 2003 server installation, we know everything is working fine. We are still developing on Windows XP.

But installing it on a Windows 2008 64 bit system make me feel a little bit uneasy.

So are there any points, where we have to watch out?
Are there any traps or tricky things to do?

Comment: thanks for your answers, feeling more secure now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no real things to worry about, **except when using Third party dll's that have been compiled specfically for x86**.

I do all my builds in ASP.NET 'Platform independent', so they run on x86 as well as x64 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile it with "Platform target" = "Any CPU", there shouldn't be any issues... remember that .NET is not native code anyway, so it's not platform dependant.

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET application deployed on Windows Server 2008 64 bits, and my development machine is Win XP 32 bits. No issues so far...

Answer (score 0):

If you consume an in-proc 32-bit COM server prepare to see it no longer working unless you create a COM+ application for that COM server.

Answer (score 0):

A point of attention is if you use PInvoke to call unmanaged libraries and the size of IntPtr structure.